# A duplicate question with more than 10k views; should the user be awarded Famous Question Badge?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While using Stackoverflow, I came across the following question:

[How would I find the maximum value in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325168/how-would-i-find-the-maximum-value-in-an-array)

The question has been marked as duplicate, and that is fine. Since, the question has 34k views, the user has been awarded `Famous Question Badge`. Now, what if a suspicious user finds a question like this: a very basic and, a question that most people search, and then, the user asks the same question. No doubt, the question will be marked as duplicate, and will get a few down votes. But as the time passes, the number of views increases and it should - since the question is of that type! Ultimately, the user gains `Famous Question Badge`.

So shouldn't `Famous Question Badge` be awarded only in that case, when the number of views is 10k+ `AND` the question hasn't been marked as `DUPLICATE`?

Comment: As long as they attract views to the site and make money for SE, I honestly don't think SE staff cares.

Comment: It seems so. But if it keeps going this way, and it is - what happens when you search something on Google related to programming, most of the links that come out are duplicate of a single question that has much better and decent answers. How would you find out that original question? Backtracking, I guess!

Comment: I don't disagree with some of your comments so far, just adding: it's not a bad thing *sometimes* to end up on the question which duplicated, as the question which duplicated might have some useful info not present on the dupe. The link to the dupe is right there, so easy to move on down the line.

Comment: @James You could easily edit the dupe in that case.